# Google Address auto-complete works as static html but not in project

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, google-maps

I'm trying to use the code from [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform?authuser=0) to autocomplete address fields. It works fine as a static HTML file, but not when I put it in an aspx page. I'm not using any runat=server on the fields and the IDs/names etc still seem to be fine when looking at the rendered HTML.

Heres the full code:

```
<table id="address">
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Street address</td>
    <td class="slimField"><input class="field" id="street_number"
          disabled="true"></input></td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="2"><input class="field" id="route"
          disabled="true"></input></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">City</td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="locality"
          disabled="true"></input></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">State</td>
    <td class="slimField"><input class="field"
          id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true"></input></td>
    <td class="label">Zip code</td>
    <td class="wideField"><input class="field" id="postal_code"
          disabled="true"></input></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Country</td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field"
          id="country" disabled="true"></input></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
  var placeSearch, autocomplete;
  var componentForm = {
    street_number: 'short_name',
    route: 'long_name',
    locality: 'long_name',
    administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
    country: 'long_name',
    postal_code: 'short_name'
  };

  function initAutocomplete() {
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        (document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
        {types: ['geocode']});
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
  }

  function fillInAddress() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    for (var component in componentForm) {
      document.getElementById(component).value = '';
      document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
      var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
      if (componentForm[addressType]) {
        var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
        document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
      }
    }
  }
  function geolocate() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var geolocation = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
          center: geolocation,
          radius: position.coords.accuracy
        });
        autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
      });
    }
  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=REDACTED&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
    async defer></script>
```

I'm getting the following JS errors in the console:

```
Test.aspx:470 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
```

And then when I click one of the auto complete suggestion:

```
Test.aspx:485 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null
```

The rendered HTML seems to come out okay, no .net traces etc

[image]

Comment: Have you tried moving the script include js tag before everything else?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to go to https://console.developers.google.com/ and select APIs.

In Google Maps APIs select Google Maps JavaScript API and make sure you enable API for Google Maps JavaScript.

Secondly, you need to create an API key:

1. Go to Credentials
2. Create new key and select Browser Key
3. No need to specify any referrers
   So you should see Any referrer allowed after you save. 
   Now you will get a key, copy that key and paste it in

   js?key=YOUR_API_KEY, from script tag, use the key which you have got in the YOUR_API_KEY place.